# how to insert jTable values into a database according to the corresponding rows?

Tags: java, mysql

My GUI:
[image: this is my GUI frame]

My databse strutuce
[image: this is my database]

I want to pass Jtable values into the database. I already inserted the two columns' values from the backend. Users should fill other data. I want to pass data from Jtable to the database according to the relevant code name. The row of jTable Which st_code equals to "FOT" should pass into the row of database which it's st_code equals to "FOT".

this is my code;

```
   private void submit_kniActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        try {

            int rows = table_kni.getRowCount();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/odemetrics", "root", "");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            String sql = "INSERT INTO `trinco_line` (stname,stcode,bookedtkt,returnedtkt,firstcls_KNI,secondcls_KNI,thirdclsA_KNI,thirdclsB_KNI,thirdclsC_KNI,total_KNI) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) where stcode = table_kni.getValueAt(row, 0)";

            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                String code = (String) table_kni.getValueAt(row, 0);
                String name = (String) table_kni.getValueAt(row, 1);
                int cls_1 = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
                int cls_2 = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
                int cls_3a = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
                int cls_3b = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
                int cls_3c = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
                int ttl = cls_1 + cls_2 + cls_3a + cls_3b + cls_3c;

                pst.setString(1, code);
                pst.setString(2, name);
                pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(bookedtkt_kni.getText()));
                pst.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(returnedtkt_kni.getText()));
                pst.setInt(5, cls_1);
                pst.setInt(6, cls_2);
                pst.setInt(7, cls_3a);
                pst.setInt(8, cls_3b);
                pst.setInt(9, cls_3c);
                pst.setInt(10, ttl);

                pst.addBatch();
            }
            pst.executeBatch();
            conn.commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "successfull!");
            conn.close();
            bookedtkt_kni.setText(null);
            returnedtkt_kni.setText(null);
            clearTable();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

Comment: use update query where stcode = 'FOT'? instead of insert; Insert is for creating new Row

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamSrivastava but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the string and then get the value of jtbable (table_kni)
according to your code, this should be:

```
        String sql = "UPDATE `trinco_line` SET `stname` = \'?\', `stcode` = \'?\', `bookedtkt` = ?, `returnedtkt` = ?, `firstcls_KNI` = ?, `secondcls_KNI` = ?, `thirdclsA_KNI` = ?, `thirdclsB_KNI` = ?, `thirdclsC_KNI` = ?, `total_KNI` = ? where `stcode` = \'?\'";

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            String code = (String) table_kni.getValueAt(row, 0);
            String name = (String) table_kni.getValueAt(row, 1);
            int cls_1 = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
            int cls_2 = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
            int cls_3a = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
            int cls_3b = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
            int cls_3c = Integer.parseInt(table_kni.getValueAt(row, 6).toString());
            int ttl = cls_1 + cls_2 + cls_3a + cls_3b + cls_3c;
            
            pst.setString(1, code);
            pst.setString(2, name);
            pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(bookedtkt_kni.getText()));
            pst.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(returnedtkt_kni.getText()));
            pst.setInt(5, cls_1);
            pst.setInt(6, cls_2);
            pst.setInt(7, cls_3a);
            pst.setInt(8, cls_3b);
            pst.setInt(9, cls_3c);
            pst.setInt(10, ttl);
            pst.setString(11, code);
```

**I hope this would help you**

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code. But it sent an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(stname,stcode,....' at line 1.

Comment: Now I had fixed it, Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: _Thanks for helping. I have a doubt. What is the purpose of  `pst.setString(11, code)` in the last line? And it will give an error again: **Parameter index out of range(9> number of parameters, which is 8) ** _

Comment: `pst.setString(11,code)` assigns value to the `stcode` in  the where condition in the SQL statement.
And this error `index out of range` must be occurring in the `for` statement, due to some row range issue.
And I am sure this error is not occurring due to my code.

Comment: I am glad to hear that, please mark my answer as accepted; This would be my first accepted.